# Intercept axios request when testing

Tags: node.js, axios, sinon, chai

I am testing a software and I would like to verify that the request being sent to an API has the correct data. This particular method creates a request with certain data, headers etc. and then makes the request to an external API via `axios`. Example code:

```
myFunction() {
    const data = {
        example: 'my data'
    };

    const headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

    const request = {
        method: 'POST',
        baseUrl: 'http://myawesome-site.com',
        url: '/api/path',
        headers,
        data,
    }

    return axios(request)
        .then(res => ...do something)
        .catch(err => ...do something else)
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way using `chai` or `sinon` to intercept the axios call and get access only to the "request" object to just verify the data being sent, I don't care about the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unit test solution, you should use `sinon.stub`:

> When you want to prevent a specific method from being called directly (possibly because it triggers undesired behavior, such as a XMLHttpRequest or similar

E.g.
`index.ts`:

```js
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

exports.myFunction = function myFunction() {
  const data = {
    example: 'my data'
  };

  const headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  };

  const request: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    baseURL: 'http://myawesome-site.com',
    url: '/api/path',
    headers,
    data
  };

  return exports
    .axios(request)
    .then(res => console.log('do something'))
    .catch(err => console.log('do something else'));
};

exports.axios = axios;
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
const mod = require('./');
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('myFunction', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should send request', async () => {
    const mResponse = { status: 200 };
    const axiosStub = sinon.stub(mod, 'axios').resolves(mResponse);
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    await mod.myFunction();
    expect(
      axiosStub.calledWith({
        method: 'POST',
        baseURL: 'http://myawesome-site.com',
        url: '/api/path',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
          example: 'my data'
        }
      })
    ).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.calledWith('do something')).to.be.true;
  });

  it('should handle request error', async () => {
    const mError = new Error('network error');
    const axiosStub = sinon.stub(mod, 'axios').rejects(mError);
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    await mod.myFunction();
    expect(
      axiosStub.calledWith({
        method: 'POST',
        baseURL: 'http://myawesome-site.com',
        url: '/api/path',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
          example: 'my data'
        }
      })
    ).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.calledWith('do something else')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  myFunction
do something
    ✓ should send request
do something else
    ✓ should handle request error


  2 passing (14ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57807855